# How to retrieve connection strings from App.config

Tags: c#, app-config

I have the following configuration in a windows forms application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ConsoleApp1.Properties.Settings.abcdConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=xxx.yyy.org;Initial Catalog=MyCatalog;"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

The following code makes several attempts to retrieve the connection string.
Nothing works.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Specialized;


namespace ConsoleApp1  
{  
class Program  
{  
static void Main(string[] args)  
        {  
            NameValueCollection sAll;  
            sAll = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;  
            Console.Write("[");  
            foreach (string s in sAll.AllKeys)  
            {  
                Console.Write(">>");  
                Console.WriteLine("Key: " + s + "Value: " + sAll.Get(s));  
            }  
            Console.Write("]");  
            Console.ReadLine();  
            Console.Write("sAll = (");  
            Console.Write(sAll);  
            Console.WriteLine(") end of sALL");  
            Console.ReadLine();  
            string keyvalue =  
 System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConsoleApp1.Properties.Settings.abcdtest19ConnectionString"];  
            Console.WriteLine("keyvalue = (" + keyvalue + ")");  
            Console.ReadLine();  
            keyvalue =   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConsoleApp1.Properties.Settings.abcdConnectionString"];  
            Console.WriteLine("keyvalue = (" + keyvalue + ")");  
            Console.ReadLine();  
            keyvalue =   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["abcdConnectionString"];  
Console.WriteLine("keyvalue = (" + keyvalue + ")");  
Console.ReadLine();  
        }  
    }  
}
```

None of these attempts produces a connection string.
This comment is to satisfy Stackoverflow's formatting requirement.

Comment: Thank you. The problem I was having was relying on telesense when a reference to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string constr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
   ConnectionStrings["ConsoleApp1.Properties.Settings.abcdConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

If you change your app.config like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="abcdConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=xxx.yyy.org;Initial Catalog=MyCatalog;"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

then

```
string constr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
   ConnectionStrings["abcdConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. The problem I was having was relying on telesense before a reference to System.Configuration had been installed in references.